# Does an excel keyboard shortcut to highlight a cell yellow exist?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there an keyboard shortcut to highlight a cell yellow (or maybe just the most recent color used)?

What I am not looking for (I want something that is preset in excel and more efficient):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> + using arrow keys to navigate to yellow in pallette
- Adding color palette to Quick Access
- Creating my own shortcut or macro (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>#some key#</kbd>)
- <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat last keystroke

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could make one. You have the ability to assign VBA macros to any key you want.

First, open up your personal macro store in the VBE. **Press ALT+F11**

Then paste this macro in:

```
Sub HighlightYellow()
'
' HighlightYellow Macro
'
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Now save your personal macro workbook and close the VBE.

**Press ALT+F8**

Then assign a shortcut to your new macro.

Answer (score 1):

Another much more flexible approach is using an [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) script:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

;  Ctrl: ^
; Shift: +
;   Alt: !

^+d::  ; Ctrl + Shift + d (change to your needs)
    Send, {Alt}
    Sleep, 10  ; wait 0.01 seconds
    Send, {h 2}{Down 6}{Right 3}{Enter}  ; Select yellow
Return
```